# R: plot(tree) how to interpret the height?

Tags: r, rpart

Is there any signification in the height of the split in a tree when it's plotted with R ?

**Example:**

```
library(rpart)
plot(tree)
```

How can we interpret the fact than the blue split is bigger than the red one?
[image]

Comment: It is probably the diminution of the mean square error. A long height  indicate a bigger diminution.

Comment: The first split is not supposed to be more important than the 2nd and so on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite murky but the documentation has the answer.

> Applies only when uniform=FALSE. Default .3. The minimum height between
>   levels is clamped at minbranch times the mean interlevel distance. Needed
>   because sometimes a split gives little or no improvement in deviance, and an
>   interlevel distance strictly proportional to the improvement would leave no room
>   for the label.

[rpart.plot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart.plot/rpart.plot.pdf)

Note : these heights can all be adjust and changed - it's just defaulting to this.

Comment: Ok so the blue one should be smaller than the red one but it would not allow to see the labels if it was proportional ?